# Application Insights Not showing Trace.TraceInformation messages

Tags: c#, .net-core, trace, azure-application-insights, system.diagnostics

I have a .net core web api project. I am simply trying to get my trace statements like below to appear in app insights:

```
Trace.TraceInformation("Hello World!");
```

I see the log in my output window when I am debugging, but after I deploy, I am not seeing any of my trace statements in the logs.... Why?

I have the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`, and `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener` packages included.

I know App insights is setup, because the requests are appearing, and I am getting one trace message from the performance metrics not getting collected (see trace message below):

```
AI: Error collecting 3 of the configured performance counters. Please check the configuration.
Counter \ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests/Sec: Failed to perform the first read for performance counter. Please make sure it exists. Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Requests/Sec, instance MyAPI.exe
Counter \ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Request Execution Time: Failed to perform the first read for performance counter. Please make sure it exists. Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Request Execution Time, instance MyAPI.exe
Counter \ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests In Application Queue: Failed to perform the first read for performance counter. Please make sure it exists. Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Requests In Application Queue, instance
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but how do you configure your app insights? Did you set value to APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY?

Answer (score 8):

Upon adding TraceListner package it adds for .NET Full version the following section:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="0">
        <listeners>
            <add name="myAppInsightsListener"
                type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Since there is no auto-registration for .NET Core, it looks like it is a matter of registering ApplicationInsightsTraceListener:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new ApplicationInsightsTraceListener());
```

Here is the complete console app (should work for other types as well) which captures all three traces (through TraceError, TraceInformation and TrackTrace):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener;

namespace CoreConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey =
                "<your ikey>";

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            Trace.Listeners.Add(new ApplicationInsightsTraceListener());
            Trace.TraceError("my error");
            Trace.TraceInformation("my information");

            TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient();
            client.TrackTrace("Demo application starting up.");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome. I will try this

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener can be used in .NET Core projects as it targets `NETSTANDARD1.3`, but configuration needs to be done manually (as indicated in above post).

The following is my `ConfigureServices` methods in `Startup` class.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry("ikey"); /* This enables entire application insights auto-collection. If you don't want anything but the traces, then ikey can be set in TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey as the above console app example. */
    services.AddMvc();
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new ApplicationInsightsTraceListener());
}
```